# Database/code design for limiting hierarchical comments at certain level?

Tags: php, postgresql, performance, database-design

I'm making small commenting app written in PHP as backend, React as frontend and PostgreSQL as database. I have table `comment` which holds all comments and it is self referencing table.

`\d+ comment`:

```
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id              | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('comment_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 website_page_id | bigint                   |           | not null |                                     | plain    |              | 
 author_id       | bigint                   |           | not null |                                     | plain    |              | 
 parent_id       | bigint                   |           |          |                                     | plain    |              | 
 content         | text                     |           |          |                                     | extended |              | 
 deleted_date    | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                     | plain    |              | 
 updated_date    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                     | plain    |              | 
 created_date    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                     | plain    |
```

On the client side I make request to get all comments, backend makes recusrive query to database to grab all comments and return them in appropriate format, then I render it.

Here is JSON of parent comment:

```
{
    id: 1
    author_id: 1
    content: "Some content"
    created_date: "2019-05-29 06:11:43+00"
    depth: 0
    parent_id: null
    replies: [...]
    updated_date: "2019-05-29 06:11:43+00"
    website_page_id: null
}
```

So each comment as depth parameter, which I use to define identation (I don't nest comments recursively like `comment -> replies -> comment -> replies`, it is only `comment and all its replies`. I do extra processing on backend to make this form, PostgreSQL returns just data as it is with `depth` definition.

I have a form for creating new comments and replies to existing comments. So far replies can nest as far as it can go (not sure about database limitations).

Here are my concerns:

- I don't want to nest forever as it kills performance (I assume). Does it really? Also, it is resonable to limit it up to `n` level by default so it does not go off the screen on the client side.
- Not sure where and how to make limitation. Whether it should be on the database level, backend or client side?

I had only one idea how to solve it, but so far it does not seem to be elegant solution. Here it is:

Ignore that it nests on the database level and just limit identation on client side, so if I defined 5 level as maximum, then anything above that would have 5 level identation. It works, but it does not help the database performace.

I am pretty sure there are other possible ways to do this, help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Recursive queries (when they take advantage of index) are really fast. It will probably take more time to nest the results in Javascript. The nesting limitation is more for the UI and not very difficult to fetch:

```sql
    with recursive
      comment_node (comment_id, parent_id, level) as (
        select comment_id, comment_parent_id, 1::int4 as level
        from comment
        where website_page_id = $*
        union all
        select c.comment_id, c.comment_parent_id, parent.level + 1 as level
        from comment as c
          inner join comment_node as parent 
            on parent.comment_id = c.parent_id 
            and parent.level < 5
      )
    select c.comment_id, cn.level, c.comment_parent_id, c.content, a.name, ...
    from comment as c
      join comment_node as cn 
        using (comment_id)
      join author as a 
        using (author_id)
```

Limiting the insertion of comments with a nesting level of 5 or more is probably not a meaningful database constraint as it does not break the data consistency.